# Displaying audio player as preview in audio post in WP3.6

Tags: shortcode, audio

I'm testing the new Wordpress 3.6 Release Candidate 2 and it's [audio] shortcode and there is something I can't figure out. The post contains the following content:

*[audio http://wpthemetestdata.files.wordpress.com/2008/06/originaldixielandjazzbandwithalbernard-stlouisblues.mp3]*

How can I extract this shortcode and it's URL and display it as a player in the post preview in `index.php`? I found the new functions at the bottom of this page ( http://codex.wordpress.org/Version_3.6 ) but I can't figure it out how can I manually display the player on the index as it is shown in `single.php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the `src` part. It should have been:

```
[audio src="http://wpthemetestdata.files.wordpress.com/2008/06/originaldixielandjazzbandwithalbernard-stlouisblues.mp3"]
```

Go on the *Shortcode* section of the [Audio / Video support in Core](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2013/04/08/audio-video-support-in-core/) post.

---

```
$post_content = 'lorem ipsum dolor [audio src="http://wpthemetestdata.files.wordpress.com/2008/06/originaldixielandjazzbandwithalbernard-stlouisblues.mp3"] lorem [audio src="http://wpthemetestdata.files.wordpress.com/2008/06/originaldixielandjazzbandwithalbernard.mp3"] ipsum ';

if( preg_match( '#\[audio\s*.*?\]#s', $post_content, $matches ) && preg_match('/"([^"]+)"/', $matches[0], $m) ){
   echo $m[1]; // echoes http://wpthemetestdata.files.wordpress.com/2008/06/originaldixielandjazzbandwithalbernard-stlouisblues.mp3

  //set as featured 

}
```

The first regex will get your first `[audio]` shortcode and the second regex will extract the URL from it by looking what's in between the double quotes.

Note that there is [`get_shortcode_regex`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_shortcode_regex) which should also help you.

Comment: The shortcode is working correctly. The problem is how can I extract the URL from the shortcode and insert it in something like Featured Image, but let's say it is Featured Audio. 
In other words I want a player in the post preview section that plays the file, which is in the content of the post.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Great! That exactly what I need.

Comment: Only one question if I may. I'm using `wp_audio_shortcode` function and I'm passing array with src="url to the mp3 file" and it does nothing. Is this the correct function and do you have any idea why it's not working? :\ @rrikesh

Comment: Is that [your question](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_audio_shortcode-not-working)? Try `echo wp_audio_shortcode( $attr );`

Comment: Yeah, that's me. Using `echo` solved the problem. How didn't I think of it.. Thank you very much!